# Smart Lock sign-in hint setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported not working

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, credentials, google-smartlockpasswords

I am trying to get user phone number with a HintRequest

```
PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
        googleApiClient, new HintRequest.Builder()
                .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
                .setEmailAddressIdentifierSupported(false)
                .build());
        try {
    startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
            REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_PHONE, null, 0, 0, 0);
} catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But getting no results and Activity.RESULT_CANCELED.

The nubmer is visible in  Settings -> About -> Status -> SIM status and can be received through TelephonyManager, but I would like to get it without requesting the phone permission.

Comment: Hmm, is the Smart Lock feature enabled in Settings > Google > Smart Lock for Passwords for all the accounts on the device. That might be interfering...

Comment: Doesn't work with it either turned on and off, if it's on, there's a progress dialog and then onActivityResult callback, if it's off, no dialog, straight to the callback. There's only one account on the device

Comment: And to check: it sounds like you can get the phone number from TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() when you have appropriate permissions? What country/carrier/OEM is the device?

Comment: Yes, I can, the device is Sony Xperia Z5 (E6653), international version I guess, was bought in Russia

Comment: Got it to work on Galaxy S6 EDGE, is it a device-specific bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was a sim card problem, didn't work with EE sim